# How to change content of char * const after it has been set (C)

Tags: c, pointers

We are dealing with a constant pointer,
so the address it holds cannot change.
But the content of that referenced memory address is supposed to be mutable...

Still,I get compilation/segmentation fault errors when trying to do so.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char * const c_ptr = "firstValue"; // now c_ptr is a const ptr to an immutable string literal, 
                                     //we can't change it unless we declare char [] instead 
    printf("%s",c_ptr);

    *c_ptr="hsdsdsd"; // better to use strcpy(c_ptr, "hsdsdsd");   

    printf("%s",c_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

> main.c: In function 'main':
>   main.c:8:8: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
>     *c_ptr="hsdsdsd";
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Read a basic C book, please. `*c_ptr` != `c_ptr`, to start with.

Comment: Read the warning. It's casting pointer->int->char.

Comment: Why would I want to change where it points to? it's a constant pointer...

Comment: If the address held within the pointer cannot change (because the pointer is `const`), and said-address points to read only data (you first read-only string literal), you're not going to be legally changing *anything*. So the answer is, you can't get there from here.

Comment: So you want to change the contents, e.g. `*c_ptr='h';`, or `strcpy(c_ptr, "hsdsdsd");`. That is also illegal in this case because `c_ptr` is currently pointing to a string literal, and storage for string literals is immutable. You could do it like this: `char c[] = "firstvalue"; char * const c_ptr = c; strcpy(c_ptr, "hsdsdsd");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the data that the pointer points at can change for a constant pointer, but not when you initialize it using a string literal. They have the rather curious property of having type `char *`, but being unable to change.

So, you can do:

```
char data[10] = "foobar";
char * const ptr = data;

printf("%s\n", ptr);  // prints foobar
*ptr = 'z';
printf("%s\n", ptr);  // prints zoobar
```

Comment: Is the standard not being changed to make string literals to be of type const char* solely for legacy code reasons?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya No, I don't think so.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Mostly it is not changed because the C committee is painfully conservative and would hate to improve the language. C++ changed it long time ago and it did not cause any major issues even for legacy code. This is because old rotten legacy code will be compiled with old rotten legacy compilers, and not with the latest and greatest standard-compliant compiler. So changes in a standard does not have nearly as much impact on old code as they fear.

Comment: @Lundin would this change cascade into other changes being required? Any particular example?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Not really. The standard library is already using const correctness. It would mean that sloppily-written code such as `void print (char* str) {puts (str); }... print("hello");` would have to be rewritten, since it is not const-correct. Also there is old rotten code which is actually abusing the fact that string literals were writeable on old systems like MS DOS. But the C standard has never claimed that string literals would be writeable, so this should be of no concern to C.

Answer (score 1):

First, C strings are null terminated char arrays, and you cannot assign arrays, you have to change each element of it.

Also, generally the compiler put string literals like `"firstValue"` into a readonly memory section, so you cannot change it, you will have to use a char array to initialize the string.

```
char s[] = "firstValue";
const char*const ptr = s;
ptr[0] = 'z';  // change contents pointed by ptr, or:
strncpy(ptr, "abc", 3);
```

Comment: Is the readonly memory section part of the stack?.  When we get out of the scope where the immutable string literal declared , does the memory it occupied turns reusable (statically allocateable) again? , or all the readonly data is set only at compilation time/beginning of execution

Comment: @IdanBanani There is no concept of "stack" required by C. And string literals have `static` storage, they don't go out of scope.

Comment: @IdanBanani It is not a part of the stack. When the function returns it does not get popped out, but the pointer itself is on the stacked and got popped out.

Answer (score 1):

`char * const c_ptr` means a non-const pointer to const data. Meaning that you made the pointer variable itself read-only, but not the pointed-at data.

If you do `*c_ptr = 'a'` then the compiler wouldn't prevent it, because you told it that the pointed-at data is read/write. Which isn't true in this case, it is a string literal and writing to it will cause *undefined behavior*, which is why you get a crash.

C11 6.4.5/7

> If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Fix the code by changing the declaration to `const char* c_ptr`.
Or alternatively `const char* const c_ptr`.

Now as it turns out, this *is* immutable, because if you would now attempt `strcpy(c_ptr, "str")` you would get an invalid pointer conversion, since the function expects a `char*`.

---

`*c_ptr="hsdsdsd";` is nonsense and will not compile on a compliant C compiler, because you try to assign an address to a single `char` variable, which is not allowed. (A constraint violation of the simple assignment rules).